# Background image wont show on the whole page

Tags: wordpress, css

Hi i have a problem with my wordpress site - i used this css to change the background of page :

.page-id-689 #primary {
    background: url('http://www.gamekey.sk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/thief-totalne.jpg') no-repeat center center !important;

-webkit-background-size: cover !important;

-moz-background-size: cover !important;

-o-background-size: cover !important;

```
background-size: cover !important;

min-height:100% !Important;
```

}

---

the problem is that the background wont show on the whole page ( Screenshot).

[image]

I already tried :

.page-id-287 #page_wrapper {  height:100% !important;  margin: 0px auto; }

---

html, body { height: 100% }

---

i also tried setting min-height to 100 % - wont work

!!! the problem is solved when i set the height to 1200px in #primary but it also causes huge problems in lower resolutions. Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Could there be a footer object at the bottom? did you inspect the source?

Comment: using 100% only makes it 100% of the container it is inside of, so unless that container is 100% of the page width, the image will not be either

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose without seeing the actual page. For all we know there's something else on that page preventing it from expanding further.

Comment: i set the footer to display:none so there shouldnt be . also if anyone want to check out that page : http://www.gamekey.sk/obchod/ ( sorry i forgot to disable the maintenance )

Comment: Working fine for me in Chrome 45 on OS X

Comment: by the way this problems occurs on other pages too ( for example  http://www.gamekey.sk/ako-ziskat-body/ ) but its alright on this page ( http://www.gamekey.sk/vyziadajte-si-hru/ )  ... seems to have something with #content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set height of all container elements to 100% down to html element http://prntscr.com/8o41id

Answer (score 0):

`background-size: cover;` covers the size of the container. Looking at your site the #primary id is only going to be as large as the content within it. If you want it to have the same height as the image so it covers the entire page you need to set an actual height value. Try adding `height: 802px;` and it will fix it, as that's the height of the image.

If you want a more graceful solution add this to the body:

```
body {
   background: url('http://www.gamekey.sk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/thief-totalne.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
}
```

And remove the `background-color` from `.st-content`.

If you want multiple pages to have different backgrounds you'll need to create a separate wrapper with a unique ID that runs the entire width and height of the page regardless of the content on it.

More information on background-size can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp